# Osmosis open Resource : NullPointerException at Parameters$Builder.loadResource

Tags: java, elasticsearch, classloader, openstreetmap, osmosis

According to the [Osmosis Github site](https://github.com/ncolomer/elasticsearch-osmosis-plugin/wiki/Quick-start#1-install-osmosis) I've installed Osmosis and I am trying to put an osm package to Elasticsearch by typing:

```
$ osmosis --read-pbf ~/osm/extract/azores-latest.osm.pbf --write-elasticsearch cluster.hosts="localhost"
```

The execution fails with:

```
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.plugin.elasticsearch.utils.Parameters$Builder.loadResource(Parameters.java:57)
at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.plugin.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchWriterFactory.buildPluginParameters(ElasticSearchWriterFactory.java:49)
at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.plugin.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchWriterFactory.createTaskManagerImpl(ElasticSearchWriterFactory.java:27)
at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.TaskManagerFactory.createTaskManager(TaskManagerFactory.java:60)
```

The ElasticSearchWriterFactory handles "plugin.properties" to the [Parameters$Builder.loadResource()](https://github.com/ncolomer/elasticsearch-osmosis-plugin/blob/1.4.x-tmp/src/main/java/org/openstreetmap/osmosis/plugin/elasticsearch/utils/Parameters.java) method. I've tried to figure the problem out by adding some log lines into the /elasticsearch-osmosis-plugin-1.3.0.jar. So I get:

```
resource: plugin.properties
getClass() : class org.openstreetmap.osmosis.plugin.elasticsearch.utils.Parameters$Builder
getClass().getClassLoader() : ClassRealm[osmosis.core, parent: null]
getClass().getName() : org.openstreetmap.osmosis.plugin.elasticsearch.utils.Parameters$Builder
getClass().getPackage() : package org.openstreetmap.osmosis.plugin.elasticsearch.utils
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resource) : null
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/opt/osmosis-0.43/" + resource) : null
```

(The last line in order to test if the relative path was the problem but that does not seem to be the problem.)

I'va also copied plugin.properties to any location / path that I could imagine to be part of interest, i.e. package root etc. ... with no success.

Anybody an idea how to solve that? Thanks very much!

Comment: Your output contains `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resource) : null`. The null pointer exception results from calling `openStream` on that.

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree, but why is it null when there is a file called "plugin.properties"? Thanks!